# Looping over vue Component

Tags: vue.js

---

Hi everyone.
I have a question about looping over a component in vuejs.
I defined a component and also a template tag which contains a table that fetches some data from database(in laravel framework).now i need to loop over this component more than 10 times and don't know how to do this!.
i used v-for in template tag but didn't work

---

```
 <div id="app"> 
<csgo><csgo>
</div>    

<template id="match-id" >
<table  style="border: 2px solid black">
<tr >
    <th>Ticket</th>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Match Type</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Sold</th>
</tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <button @click='buy({{$user->profile->account_money}})' v-bind:style="objectStyle"  :disabled=Bstate >BUY</button>     </td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" max="10" step="1" v-model="ticketNumber"></td>
        <td>{{$matches[0]->matchType}}</td>
        <td>{{$matches[0]->matchDate}}</td>
        <td>{{$matches[0]->matchTime}}</td>
        <td>{{$matches[0]->price}}</td>
        <td>@{{soldTicket}}@{{sold}}</td>


    </tr>

</table>
</template>


<script>



        Vue.component('csgo', {

            template: '#match-id',
            data: function () {

                return {

                    money: '',
                    sold: '',
                    state: false,
                    Estate: false,
                    Bstate: false,
                    error: '',
                    ticketNumber: 1,

                    objectStyle: {
                        background: 'lightgreen'
                    },


                }
            },


            props: ['matches'],

            methods: {


                buy: function (num) {

                    tempNum = num
                    num -= 1000

                    if (num < 0) {
                        this.money = tempNum
                    }

                    vm = this

                    axios.post('/matches/csgo-buy-ticket', {tickets: 
             Math.floor(vm.ticketNumber)}).then(function (response) {


                        if (typeof (response.data) == 'string') {
                            vm.error = response.data
                            vm.state = false
                            vm.Estate = !vm.state
                            vm.Bstate = false
                        }
                        else {
                            vm.money = response.data[0]
                            vm.sold = response.data[1]
                            vm.state = true
                            vm.Estate = !vm.state
                            vm.Bstate = true
                            vm.objectStyle.background = 'darkred'
                        }
                    })

                },

            },
            computed: {
                soldTicket: function () {
                    vm = this
                    axios.get('/sold-ticket').then(function (response) {

                        return vm.sold = response.data
                    })
               },

                account_money: function () {

                    var vm = this
                    axios.get('/user-account-money').then(function 
             (response) {

                        vm.money = response.data

                    })

                },
            },
        })

    new Vue({

        el:'#app',

        data:{
            list:[''],
        },
        created:function () {

            vm = this
            axios.get('/csgo-matches').then(function (response) {

              console.log(response.data)
                vm.list = response.data

            })

        },
           })
         </script>
```

Comment: Show the Javascript.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Components-and-v-for

Comment: @Bert, do you need any code to tell him if iteration over component is possible or not?

Comment: @Roy. completely irrelevant. Components are not treated by Vue like ordinary js object. That's the problem.